# How can I see is user auth or not in same API

Tags: laravel

I have project laravel10.
I have some of API.
I use Laravel Sanctum for Auth .
Now in header API I have some information appear when user Auth.

Header API:

```
  "data": {
    "UserData": [],
    "navbarData": [
      {
        "title": "Home",
        "path": "/"
      },
      {
        "title": "AboutUs",
        "path": "/AboutUs"
      },
      {
        "title": "ContactUs",
        "path": "/ContactUs"
      },

      ]

  }
```

and this is function:

```
public function index(Request $request):JsonResponse
{
    //

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        
        $this->body['UserData'] = UserResource::collection($user);
    } else {
        $this->body['UserData'] = [];
      
    }

    $Categories = Menu::query()->where('active', 1)->orderBy('rank', 'ASC')->get();
    
    $this->body['navbarData'] = MenuResource::collection($Categories);

   return response()->json(['data'=>$this->body,  'error'=>''], 200);


}
```

this Array get data when User Authenticate

My login API:

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
{

    $validate = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',

    ]);



    if (Auth::attempt($validate)) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->update(['fcm_token' => $request->fcm_token]);

        $this->message = __('front.login_successfully');
        $this->body['user'] = UserResource::make($user);
         $token = $user->createToken($user->name);
         $user = Auth::user();
         return response()->json(['message'=>$this->message ,'token'=>$token->plainTextToken,'user'=>$this->body, 'error'=>''], 200);
    } else {

        $this->message = __('front.auth_failed');
        return response()->json(['message'=>$this->message , 'error'=>''], 200);
    }


}
```

I know must use token,
but how display Array in header API in case I have token  or not?

i want if i have token "UserData": [ { "name": "name", "email": "email", }] and if i haven't token "UserData": []

Comment: add the `auth:sanctum` middleware to your route and include the token in your request

Comment: if i do this 
if i don't have token i will have "Unauthenticated"
i want if i have token get data, and if i haven't token doesn't get data,

Comment: of course if the token does not match you get "Unauthenticated", it's the same if you try to login with incorrect password.

Comment: i want if i have token "UserData": [ { "name": "name", "email": "email", }]

and if i haven't token  "UserData": []

Comment: make the "navbarData" into a separate request that can be performed by both authenticated users and guests, and your "userData" into a route protected by `auth` middleware.

Comment: i want this in same api because it's header so i have header item's and user data

Comment: you would have to drop the middleware and manually authenticate the user using the "sanctum" guard, check the `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware.